# migrating sql server 2008r2 cluster from hyper-v to nutanix, persisting instance names

Tags: domain-name-system, sql-server, hyper-v, migration, nutanix

We have a SQL Server 2008R2 cluster with 2 servers called vp-sql01 and vp-sql02, both running Windows Server 2008R2. Both of these servers have 1 instance, respectively called SQL1\I1 and SQL2\I2.

We have set up a new Nutanix environment, running multiple VMs, including the new SQL cluster running Windows Server 2016 Standard and SQL Server 2016.

Our application VM's have been V2V'd, so are running their older Windows Server 2008R2 and Windows Server 2012 versions. Here we have connectionstrings in multiple applications, pointing to the old SQL1\I1 and I2 instances.

Because a lot of the Third Party firms that we are working with ask alot of money to change these connection strings (some need to assess if the new version of SQL will still work), we would like to just move all the databases to the new instances on the Nutanix cluster called SQLZ1\ZI1 and SQLZ2\ZI2. Then we ofcourse need to point a connection to the old instance, to the new.

- connection to SQL1\I1 => SQLZ1\ZI1
- connection to SQL2\I2 => SQLZ2\ZI2

We were thinking about a DNS alias, but is this the best way? And if it is, how could we do it? Can someone point us to more information?